# build php Mysql query for four input variables, ignore if any variable is empty

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am building an dynamic SQL Query. I have four input values which is passing from Android to PHP MySQL. The user may enter all values or leave some values empty. I want build an SQL query if the input of the any variable present. The complete SQL Query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE `imdb_rat` IN ($val1) OR `Rotten_rate` IN ('$val2')  OR $stringgen OR `Year` IN ('$val4')
```

The four inputs are $val1, $val2, $stringgen & $val4.

I've tried the below steps but it's not working:

```
$QueryString="SELECT * FROM Moviess WHERE 1=1"; 

if (!empty($val1)) { 
$QueryString=$QueryString+" imdb_rat` IN ($val1)"; 
} 

if (!empty($val2)) { 
$QueryString=$QueryString+" `Rotten_rate` IN ($val2)"; 
} 

if (!empty($val4)) { 
$QueryString=$QueryString+" OR `Year` IN ($val4)"; 
} 

echo $QueryString;
$result = mysql_query($QueryString);
```

How to build SQL query when if any input is present otherwise ignore the variable in the query?

Comment: if (!empty($val4) && isset($val4)) { 
    $QueryString=$QueryString+" OR `Year` IN ($val4)"; 
}

Comment: @Niyaz `empty()` does the same as `isset()` but also checks if the variable isn't empty so `(!empty($val4) && isset($val4))` is like writing double code

Comment: empty checks undefined ?

Comment: @Niyaz well if it hasn't been set it's also empty

Comment: Thanks for you answer bro , got it .

Comment: @user2269164 Has any of the answers helped you? If so then please check it as answered. If not maybe you need to add more info in the question

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($val4) && !empty($val4)) { 
      $QueryString.=$QueryString+" OR `Year` IN ($val4)"; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Niyaz, it is useful to everyone if you could [edit] your answer to explain the _why_ this should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$QueryString="SELECT * FROM Moviess WHERE 1=1"; 

if (!empty($val1)) { 
$QueryString .= " imdb_rat` IN ($val1)"; 
} 

if (!empty($val2)) { 
$QueryString .= " `Rotten_rate` IN ($val2)"; 
} 

if (!empty($val4)) { 
$QueryString .= " OR `Year` IN ($val4)"; 
} 

echo $QueryString;
$result = mysql_query($QueryString);
```

`.=` is used to concatonate to the first variable mention. The use of `+` in a string is used in JavaScript. `+` in PHP would mean `1 + 1 = 2` which isn't what you want for a string.

Also note that `mysql_*` is deprecated and is removed in PHP7 instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`